# Search text including parenthesis using wildcard * symbol

Tags: php, mysql, match

I am trying to do a match statement with wildcard matching aka with * symbol.

```
MATCH(videos.title) AGAINST('blah blah (blah)*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It fails every time a search text has a parenthesis inside of it.

This will work.

```
MATCH(videos.title) AGAINST('blah blah*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

With the wildcard asterisk matching symbol but once the search text has a parenthesis it breaks with asterisk symbol next to it.

What I am trying to do is like what hackingwithphp did with +nice* boolean query where it matches with nice, nicely, nicety, nice language, etc

http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/18/advanced-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes

Comment: Maybe `*` doesn't work the way you're expecting.

Comment: See: [12.9.2 Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html): The asterix should be appended to the word to be affected. In your first code it's not behind a word.